# Need Validation for length of name field

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I am creating my first ASP.Net Webforms application.  I need to create a form that has a name field that needs to be 3 to 50 characters long.  `RangeValidation` seems insufficient as it only tests the numeric value.

Here is what it looks like so far:

```
<li>
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
        CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RegularExpressionValidator` instead with this Regex `.{3,50}`. Below is an explanation of how that Regex works:

```
.{3,50}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ba1Rhx0VeVNRkshl)